# 'Error: void value not ignored as it ought to be' but I'm not setting anything with a void?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I've been trying to iterate though a list of objects, but it keeps throwing this error at me whenever I try to call my display function.

**Main source**

```
Stocks gamestop("Gamestop", "GMSP", 21.45f);
Stocks heroShop("Heros Shop", "HESP", 0.35f);
Stocks amazon("Amazon", "AMZN", 8.36f);
Stocks iphone("Iphone", "IPHN", 56.34f);
Stocks youtube("Youtube", "YUTB", 89.35f);

list<Stocks> listStocks = 
{
    gamestop,
    heroShop,
    amazon,
    iphone,
    youtube
};

list<Stocks>::iterator itr;
itr = listStocks.begin();

for (itr; itr != listStocks.end(); itr++)
{
    *itr->display();
}

return 0;
```

**Stocks header**

```
    string companyName{"Default"};
    string tickerSymbol{"DEFAULT"};
    float sharePrice{10.25f};
    
    Stocks();
    Stocks(string company, string ticker, float price);
    Stocks(const Stocks& orig);
    virtual ~Stocks();
    
    void display();
```

**Stocks source**

```
Stocks::Stocks(string company, string ticker, float price)
{
    companyName = company;
    tickerSymbol = ticker;
    sharePrice = price;
    
}

void Stocks::display()
{
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << endl;
    
    cout << "Company Name:\t" << companyName << endl; 
    cout << "Ticker Symbol:\t" << tickerSymbol << endl;
    cout << "Share Price:\t" << sharePrice << endl;
}
```

this is what I currently have setup for my stocks class is there something I am doing wrong with the stocks class?

Comment: I think you're asking about the behavior of `display()`, a function you have not shown us.

Comment: @DrewDormann It does as it says, it displays the information, but here is it,

`void Stocks::display()
{
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << endl;
    
    cout << "Company Name:\t" << companyName << endl; 
    cout << "Ticker Symbol:\t" << tickerSymbol << endl;
    cout << "Share Price:\t" << sharePrice << endl;
}`

Comment: *"it only returns the default values"* -- what is "it"? I see nothing being returned except `0`, and that's even if you accept that there is an omitted line where a function begins.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mre].

Comment: One test for a [mre] is that the code can be copied from your question into a file (or online compiler), then compiled to **reproduce** your error. What happens if you copy the code from your question and try to compile it in its current state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cpp
*itr->display();
```

should be:

```cpp
itr->display();
```

`itr->` is a shorthand for `(*itr).`

Adding an extra dereference (`*`) makes it `*(itr->display());`

`display()` returns `void`, which cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: There is a typo in your answer. I think `it` should be `itr`.